# Spark scheduler thersholds

Tags: apache-spark, configuration

I'm running on top of Spark some analysis tool that creates plenty of overhead,  so computations takes a lot more time. When I run it I get this error:

```
16/08/30 23:36:37 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /132.68.60.126:36922
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:384)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:313)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/08/30 23:36:37 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 0 on 132.68.60.126: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
```

I guess this happens because the scheduler thinks the executor failed, so it starts another one.

The workload is a simple string search (grep), both master and slave are local so there aren't suppose to be any failures. When running without the overheads things are fine.

The question is - can I configure those timeout thresholds somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with `spark.network.timeout 10000000` on *spark-defaults.conf*.

Comment: I got the same error and I used both `--conf spark.network.timeout 10000000` and `--conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval 10000000` but it did not get resolved. any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error even if I tried many things.My job used to get stuck throwing this error after running a very long time. I tried few work around which helped me to resolve. Although, I still get the same error by at least my job runs fine.

- one reason could be the executors kills themselves thinking that they
  lost the connection from the master. I added the below configurations
  in spark-defaults.conf file.

  spark.network.timeout 10000000 
  spark.executor.heartbeatInterval 10000000

basically,I have increased the network timeout and heartbeat interval

- The particular step which used to get stuck, I just cached the
  dataframe that is used for processing (in the step which used to get
  stuck)

Note:- These are work arounds, I still see the same error in error logs but the my job does not get terminated.